# Deserialization of JSON with integer keys and string value in Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, fasterxml

I have to de-serialize and serialize back a simple JSON having integer key and string value in Spring-boot using Feign library. I know, if the key is in String, this is pretty straight forward in Spring-boot with automatic serialization and de-serialization. My JSON looks like :

```
"avatar": {
            "48x48": "https://wfrjira.int.abc.com/secure/useravatar?ownerId=person&avatarId=1234",
            "24x24": "https://wfrjira.int.abc.com/secure/useravatar?size=small&ownerId=person&avatarId=1234"
        }
```

My POJO bean with proper getters and setters class is :

```
class Avatar {
private String _48x48;
private String _24x24;

public Avatar() {
}

public Avatar(String _48x48, String _24x24) {
    this._48x48 = _48x48;
    this._24x24 = _24x24;
}                               Getters and Setter ...
```

I am getting following error :

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
> Error while extracting response for type [class [Lcom.XXXXXX.JiraResourceData;] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `[Lcom.XXXXXX.JiraResourceData;` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `[Lcom.XXXXXX.JiraResourceData;` out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
> feign.codec.DecodeException: Error while extracting response for type [class [Lcom.XXXXXX.JiraResourceData;] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `[Lcom.XXXXXX.JiraResourceData;` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `[Lcom.XXXXXX.JiraResourceData;` out of START_OBJECT token
> at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]

I understand that I need to declare the variables in Avatar class with the name matching with the keys of JSON but strings can't be declared starting with numeric. Is there any other way to resolve this in Spring-boot? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can write your own deserializer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your last `JSON` line has a comma. Remove that. Furthermore, the `JSON` should be embedded in another set of brackets.

Also, annotate your class with `@JsonRootName("avatar")` since your class is uppercase but your `JSON` is lowercase.

Furthermore, you probably want to rename your fields to the field names in the `JSON` or annotate these with `@JsonProperty("my-json-name")`

Comment: The comma was a typo, I corrected it. Actually I extracted the JSON out of a larger JSON in which other elements are normal string key and string value pairs. The problem with renaming those String fields is that String field cannot be something starting with a number.

Comment: Allright, usually converting JSON to DTO I personally use plugins in IntelliJ to copy in the JSON and it will make a DTO for me. I suggest you do the same, since it is a cumbersome task otherwise.